# Missing Bottom Margin in Chrome When Fullscreen with Flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, webkit, flexbox

I have an interesting problem in Webkit (Chrome and Opera) when using the Fullscreen API. I'm using Flexbox to do some basic layout and I'm fullscreening that element. When not in fullscreen, my top and bottom margins are correct. But when I go into fullscreen with an element that has been set to `display:flex`, the bottom margin does not show. This problem doesn't occur in IE or Firefox, but does occur in Chrome, Opera and Chrome for Android.

Am I missing some CSS here? Or is this a bug? If it is a bug, is there a work around?

Note: I am only targeting the latest browsers that support the candidate recommendation implementation of Flexbox http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

- **JSFiddle Markup:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/dCceV/
- **JSFiddle Show:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/dCceV/show/

---

```
section
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:white;

    display:flex; //<--- If I remove this, it works fine (but my layout gets messed up)

    overflow: auto; //<--- So I can scroll content

}

article
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

<section id="section">
    <article>
        //Lots of Content
    </article>
</section>

var element = document.getElementById("section");
if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen)
{
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working demo?

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle links.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Margins aren't supposed to collapse on flex items.  Also, if you change the margins to padding, the same thing happens.